# Options when US Passport is stuck in renewal

Tags: usa, passport-renewals

The US state department currently quotes US passport renewal times as 5-7 weeks. I have no upcoming travel booked so this may be a good opportunity to get this over with. However, there is a non-trivial chance, that business travel might come up on short notice

What are my options here ?

1. The State Department offers "Expedited at Agency" if you have travel booked within three days. However it's not guaranteed. Can you go this route if you already have submitted your passport for renewal? Does the passport actually have to be expired to do this?
2. I also have a German passport, so I can easily leave and enter the travel country on the German passport. Can I return with a German passport and an ESTA if the US passport is stuck in renewal?

Comment: "Does the passport actually have to be expired to do this?": No. "Can I return with a German passport and an ESTA if the US passport is stuck in renewal?": It's probably impossible to say for certain until you actually try. You might get away with it one time and not another time. There are many questions on the site that discuss the relevant issues. I don't know whether you can expedite after submitting a normal mail renewal, nor how you would do it, which is why I'm not posting an answer.